# Handlebars: How do I add a `rel=preload` parameter to a `{{stylesheet}}` tag?

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I have

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' }}}
```

Which outputs:

```
<link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want to add `rel="preload"` to that link tag

So far I've tried variations of:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' rel="preload" }}}

{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' rel:preload }}}

{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' 'rel':'preload' }}}
```

Without any success.

Would anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Stylesheet helper documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#stylesheet), your first variation might work.

In fact, trying it myself, it appears to work just as you have written it:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' rel="preload" }}}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, by any chance did you got a chance to add like this. ? 
<link rel="preload" href="/assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet';"/>
basically, i am adding critical css and thinking this will work..

Comment: Instead of `<link rel="preload" href="/assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet';"/>`, try `<link rel="preload" href="{{cdn 'assets/css/theme.css'}}" type="text/css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet';"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, let me give a try.

Comment: This is working fine :-)

Comment: This is working fine in local, but when it is deployed its not

Comment: Without seeing your file structure, I wouldn't be able to offer insight here. You could also try manipulating the stylesheet tag like this: `{{{concat (first (split (stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css' rel="preload") '>')) 'onload="this.onload=null; this.rel=stylesheet;">'}}}`